# How to dump in a file the Auto/Local variables from MS Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, variables, local, auto

Is it possible to dump in a txt/excel file all the Auto and Local variables from MS Visual C++ 2010 Express?

I'm trying to make a log and I need to dump all the variables in a file to send it and read the values later.

Comment: Do you mean a list of all variables that aren't global, or "show the values of the local variables as the code runs". Neither is trivially available as a feature of the language, but I guess there may be ways to achieve both, with sufficient effort. [Bear in mind that this may change the behaviour of a program, as using a variable in an additional way, e.g. printing it out, will affect the compiler's code generation - for example a loop counter can be completely removed when iterating through an array may be changed into a pointer, but if you use the variable elsewhere, it can't]

Comment: I tried to debug a solution and the stack trace listed some problem. Unless those problems were resolved, it couldn't continue the debug but in order to fix them I had to send the details about the stack trace to an acquaintance (I'm a newbie so I can't solve problems by myself yet). I was asked to send the values of auto/local variables (these http://i.imgur.com/lzv5SQg.png ) but I noticed that clicking "+" and opening those trees, there were more than 40-50 sub-trees so I was trying to find a way to dump all those trees/sub-trees and the respective values in a txt or excel file.